# If it wasn't / hadn't been for

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood

Would I rather say

> He would have forgotten about the incident, if it wasn't for the huge backpack

or

> He would have forgotten about the incident, if it hadn't been for the huge backpack

or are even both wrong? (If so, how could I say that the backpack has been the reason for him to not forget about the incident in an equal manner?)

Comment: You missed out *... if it **weren't** for the huge backpack*, which I'd probably be more likely to use. Particularly if the *huge backpack* still had current significance, noting that OP's second alternative *(hadn't been)* somewhat implies that the backpack issue is very much a thing of the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would offer this rephrasing:

> He would have forgotten about the incident were it not for the huge backpack.

This eliminates some of the uncertainty around the conditional phrase, and applies "weren't" as the verb. In most cases, the presence of a desired or notional alternative outcome carries with it the use of the subjunctive "were" for the verb.

Comment: Plural "were" or subjunctive "were"?

Comment: Sorry - you're absolutely right. Subjunctive. Edited accordingly.

Comment: I think the *verb - subject* reordering is formal/dated by comparison with ***if** + standard word order*. Here's the NGram showing how [*if **it were** not for...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+it+not+for%2C(if+it+were+not+for)%2B(if+it+weren%27t+for)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwere%20it%20not%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28if%20it%20were%20not%20for%29%20%2B%20%28if%20it%20were%20not%20for%29%3B%2Cc0) was less common until a century ago, but is now the *more* common form.

Comment: Plural _were_ **is** "subjunctive" _were_. If it sounds like a duck and spells like a duck, you can call it anything you want and it'll still be a duck.  And this one is the least likely construction; nobody speaks like this except in Oscar Wilde plays. And that style is out of order with a modern prole word like _backpack_. Put together, the sentence is incongruous, and would draw attention. If that's what  you want, cool. Otherwise, beginners should avoid these vertiginous heights.

Comment: @JohnLawler We respectfully disagree. A structure of age is not inherently wrong, and in this case offers an alternative that steers away from a problem many such beginners confront - excessive commas. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: I have to add a note that I'm a non-native speaker. Thus, I am heavily interested in developing the best possible idea of how the sentences I write actually are perceived by potential readers. The sentence in question should fit neatly into the rest of the text and should not draw particular attention. It is intended as a mere statement, in order to point out the fact that the backpack is a notably one, which stays in mind

Comment: @user2422960 Although Mr. Lawler disagrees, I don't find this construct quite so "incongruous." English beginners tend to overuse commas, leading to such fundamental issues as comma splices and run-on sentences. Such things stand out, and are sins far worse than sounding "like an Oscar Wilde play." As a result, I'm happy to stand by the construction I offered in this answer. Good luck in your learning.

Comment: I believe strongly that 'were' cannot replace 'had been', as I tried to explain here below.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with your reasoning. Thanks for your input, @Sankarane

Comment: Grammatical rules govern these two clauses in such a sentence, which pertain to the use of appropriate tenses, David W. This is not my reasoning :-) Regards.

Comment: Grammatical rules call for the subjunctive "were." Obviously, we will have to agree to disagree, @Sankarane. Have a great evening.

Comment: Sorry about my persistence... 

Of course, as in my example in my original answer. Here it is, again:

"He would forget about the incident were it not for the huge backpack."

Here, "were" is right, since the verb "forget" is in conditional present tense.

But with "would have forgotten" it should change to past perfect tense (had been). 

Have a great evening!

.